# count with IF condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

How I will add `IF condition`, if for a single student there are five subjects data has been inserted then I want to restrict it for six data.... As I have done this in below query but I cannot add `IF` with this.

```
SELECT Count(Student_ID) as 'StudentCount' 
FROM tbCourseSemOne
where Student_ID=1 
Having Count(Student_ID) < 6 and Count(Student_ID) > 0;
```

Comment: add simple input & output for better understand

Comment: What does this means: if for a single student there are **five** subject data has been inserted then i want to restrict it for **six** data?

Comment: Do you want to exclude students with more than 5 entries, or only include 5 entries per student? Some example data and input/output would be helpful..

Comment: how simple input and output @shamimreza

Comment: You should add your sample data, and expected result you want (That's what simple input and output mean). So we could know logic of which data you want to restrict to the result.

Comment: yes sirr...5 entries per student not more than 5 fives per student @StevieG

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to prevent inserts of more than 5 subjects per Student in the table.

This would usually be done with an **after-statement trigger**. This kind of trigger doesn't fire after each row, but only after the completed command. You could then count entries and raise an error when there are too many.

However, as far as I know, SQL Server doesn't provide after-statement triggers. So I think this is **not possible in SQL Server**. (I may be wrong, though, of course.)

Comment: what should be the solution for it as you got it ?@Thorsten Kettner

Comment: As mentioned I cannot think of any way to get this working fully automatically in SQL Server. Maybe you could add a column `counter` to the table with a constraint `counter in(1,2,3,4,5)` and a unique key on `(student_id, counter)`. Thus you could only insert five subjects per student, but you would have to deal with finding the desired `counter` on insert.

Comment: that is the problem sir @Thorsten Kettner

Answer (score 0):

I think what your are searching for is **IF NOT [EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188336.aspx)**, If your query returns more than one row it will return FALSE

```
If NOT Exist(Your Query)
Begin
  //Your insert query
End
```

**Update:**

```
IF Exists (SELECT 1  FROM CourseSemOne where Student_ID=1 Having Count(Student_ID) > 5)
BEGIN
    Print 'Your Error Message'
END
```

Comment: Declare @Counter int 
    Set @Counter=(SELECT Count(Student_ID) as 'StudentCount' FROM CourseSemOne 
where Student_ID=1 Having Count(Student_ID) < 6 and Count(Student_ID) > 0)
if(@Counter <6)
print'Sorry! You cannot add more than five subject data for a single stduent'
else
print'Insert Code'

Comment: after one month I Solved this logic my self

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Counter int 
Set @Counter=(SELECT Count(Student_ID) as 'StudentCount' FROM CourseSemOne
```

where Student_ID=1 Having Count(Student_ID) < 6 and Count(Student_ID) > 0)
if(@Counter <6)
print'Sorry! You cannot add more than five subject data for a single stduent'
else
print'Insert Code'
select * from CourseSemOne order by Student_ID;

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Counter int 
Set @Counter=(SELECT Count(Student_ID) as 'StudentCount' FROM CourseSemOne 
              where Student_ID=1 Having Count(Student_ID) < 6 and Count(Student_ID) > 0)
if(@Counter <6)
print'Sorry! You cannot add more than five subject data for a single stduent'
else
print'Insert Code'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Counter int 
Set @Counter=(SELECT isnull(Count(Student_ID),0) as 'StudentCount' FROM     CourseSemOne  where Student_ID=1 )
if(@Counter >5)
print'Sorry! You cannot add more than five subject data for a   single         stduent'
else

print'Insert Code'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
               Solved myself :)
               string sql = "SELECT Count(Student_ID) FROM CourseSemOne where Student_ID='"+Student_ID+"' Group by Student_ID ";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CS_DB;Integrated Security=True");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();

                if (count <5 && count >=0)
                {
                    obj.insertSemCourseOne(Student_ID, Course_Code, Course_Title, Total_Marks, Obtain_Marks, Grade, Value, Cr_Hours, Grade_Point, GPA, CGPA);
                   // DatabaseConnnectionClass.UserMessage("Added");
                    MessageBox.Show("Added Subject");
                    Dataloaddd();
                }
                else
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Sorry!For this Student ID = "+Student_ID+" You cannot add more than 5 data.");
                }
```